# Action not doing anything on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I'm trying to set up a PinPayments hosted fields payment form and I don't what I'm doing wrong but the `<submit>` button is not doing anything. Doesn't reload the page, doesn't do anything. The payment.php file is working correctly as when I manually enter that in to the URL it works fine.

The form is sat within a Drupal CMS. When I drop the exact same HTML and JS in to a simple .html file it the submit button then actually works. So I'm completely stumped.

This is the documentation I followed:

https://pinpayments.com/developers/integration-guides/hosted-fields

Code:

HTML

```
<form action="/payment.php" id="payment_form" method="post"><label for="name">Full name</label>
<div id="name"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the 'name' field --></div>

<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_name">&nbsp;</div>
<label for="number">Card number</label>

<div id="number"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the 'number' field --></div>

<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_number">&nbsp;</div>
<label for="cvc">CVC</label>

<div id="cvc"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the 'cvc' field --></div>

<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_cvc">&nbsp;</div>
<label for="expiry">Expiry</label>

<div id="expiry"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the 'expiry' field --></div>

<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_expiry">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="pin-form-field" id="publishable_api_key"><input id="thisField" type="hidden" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_line1"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_line2"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_city"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_postcode"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_state"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
&nbsp;

<div class="pin-form-field" id="address_country"><input id="thisField" type="text" /></div>
<br />
<input type="submit" />&nbsp;</form>
```

Script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.pinpayments.com/pin.hosted_fields.v1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    fields = HostedFields.create({
      /* Set this to true when testing. Set it to false in production. */
      sandbox: true,

      /*
        These are the CSS styles for the input elements inside the iframes. Inside each iframe
        is a single input with its id set to name, number, cvc or expiry.

        When the input has a valid value, it will have the 'hosted-fields-valid' class. When
        the input has an invalid value, it will have the 'hosted-fields-invalid' class.
      */
      styles: {
        'input': {
          'font-size': '16px',
          'font-family': 'helvetica, tahoma, calibri, sans-serif',
          'color': '#3a3a3a', 'border':'1px solid #000', 'height':'2em;'
        },

        '.hosted-fields-invalid:not(:focus)': {
          'color': 'red'
        }
      },

      /*
        The fields object defines the fields to be created. All four fields are required
        (name, number, cvc, expiry).

        Each field requires a selector for the element in which to create an iframe. Optionally,
        you can define placeholder text and a label selector (the CSS selector of the label
        element for that particular field).
      */
      fields: {
        name: {
          selector: '#name',
          placeholder: 'Roland Robot'
        },
        number: {
          selector: '#number',
          placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
        },
        cvc: {
          selector: '#cvc',
          placeholder: '123'
        },
        expiry: {
          selector: '#expiry',
          placeholder: '12/34'
        }

      }
    });
  });

  $(function () {
    /* The submit event for the form. */

    $('#payment_form').on('submit', function(e){
      /*
        If there's no card_token element in the form, then tokenisation hasn't happened yet.
        Ensure the default action is prevented and call a function to tokenise the field.
      */
      if( $('#card_token').length == 0 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        tokenizeHostedFields();
      }
    });
  });

  /*
    Tokenises the hosted fields. Appends a hidden field for card_token on success, adds
    error messages otherwise.
  */

  function tokenizeHostedFields(){

    /*
      Tokenise the card. This requires address details not included in the hosted fields
      which can be pulled from elsewhere (such as other form elements).
    */
    fields.tokenize(
      {
        publishable_api_key: 'pk_wkHM76EknXUavjrEYZlvNQ',
        address_line1: 'Unit 42',
        address_line2: '123 Example St',
        address_city: 'Perth',
        address_postcode: '6000',
        address_state: 'WA',
        address_country: 'Australia'
      },
      function(err, response){
        if(err) {
          /*
            Example error:

            {
              error: "invalid_resource",
              error_description: "One or more parameters were missing or invalid",
              messages: [
                {
                  code: "number_invalid",
                  message: "A valid card number is required",
                  param: "number"
                }
              ]
            }
          */

          handleErrors(err);
          return;
        }

        /*
          Example successful response:

          {
            address_city: "Perth",
            address_country: "Australia",
            address_line1: "Unit 42",
            address_line2: "123 Example St",
            address_postcode: "6000",
            address_state: "WA",
            customer_token: null,
            display_number: "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0000",
            expiry_month: 12,
            expiry_year: 2034,
            name: "Roland Robot",
            primary: null,
            scheme: "visa",
            token: "card_Evv6AG9AzI2Gg0n3FrmQdw"
          }

        */

        /* Append a hidden element to the form with the card_token. */

        $('<input>').attr({
          type: 'hidden',
          id: 'card_token',
          name: 'card_token',
          value: response.token
        }).appendTo('#payment_form');

        /* Resubmit the form with the added card_token input. */
        $('#payment_form').submit();
      }
    );
  }

  /* Handles rendering of the error messages to the form. */

  function handleErrors(err){
    /* Clear any existing error messages. */

    $('.error_message').text('');

    /* Add each error message to their respective divs. */

    err.messages.forEach(function(errMsg){
      $('#errors_for_' + errMsg.param).text(errMsg.message);
    });
  }
</script>
```

payment.php

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test-api.pinpayments.com/1/charges');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "amount=400&currency=AUD&description=test charge&email=roland@pinpayments.com&ip_address=203.192.1.172&card[number]=5520000000000000&card[expiry_month]=05&card[expiry_year]=2021&card[cvc]=123&card[name]=Roland Robot&card[address_line1]=42 Sevenoaks St&card[address_line2]=&card[address_city]=Lathlain&card[address_postcode]=6454&card[address_state]=WA&card[address_country]=Australia&metadata[OrderNumber]=123456&metadata[CustomerName]=Roland Robot");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'REMOVED THE SECRET KEY!!!' . ':' . '');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: What do you see in your network tab as you do this? I copied and pasted this code line for line and it works for me. Note though, that if you don't get a successful response back from the pinpayments api the callback url (you're `/payments.php`) won't get hit.

Comment: It works for me as soon as I put it in to a basic HTML file. It's running in Drupal, it's picking up the form fields to render in an iframe/throws an error if a field isn't inputted right etc, it's just not doing anything when clicking the submit button. Totally stumped as to why. It's picking up the hosted fields JS as it's wrapping each input area with an iframe as well, so don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I don't know anything about drupal to be honest. Maybe tag this with "Drupal" and "PHP" because I don't think this is necessarily a JS question.

Comment: Where in Drupal did you put this? Inside a page or block?